# Azure Load Balancing HTTP probe not working

Tags: load-balancing, azure

I did the following :

- Made an Azure load balancer to an availability group of 2 VMs
- Created an HTTP health probe to monitor the site going to `/`
- Verified that the site would respond to `http://10.0.0.7:80/`

The site doesn't come up.

The firewall is fine. If I switch to a TCP probe on port 80then the site comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I ended up with a space in the path name shown here. Removing it (or creating a file called EXPLETIVE.HTM in the root of the website) solved the issue.

[image]

This was verified in my IIS server logs

```
2017-04-25 00:08:13 10.0.0.7 GET /+ - 80 - 168.63.129.16 Load+Balancer+Agent - 404 0 0 0
```

The plus symbol represents the space.

Comment: Those spaces can kill!

Comment: @CtrlDot I still don't understand why no hostname field for VMS - but I've had enough load balancing for one day!

Comment: You require hitting a particular host header for your http probes?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out exactly how I set everything up but I wanted to be able to disable certain sites from particular nodes for various reasons and if host header was recognized I could just stop that site and it would be removed automatically

Comment: Azure App Gateway might be a better fit.  Azure LB is only a layer 4 device, so you won't be able to do that.

Comment: I'm not expecting passthrough of the host header - just being able to probe a URL with a hostname. Azure seems to have some odd limitations sometimes.

Comment: I just don't understand why I can't create a probe on `http://example.com/` and why instead it has to be `http://10.0.0.1/`. There's plenty of ways a web app can fail on only one server without the whole IIS going down!

Comment: The probe hits every IP configured in the backend pool.

Comment: Right but let's say I have `http://cats.com` and `http://dogs.com` on two different nodes. What if `dogs.com` goes down on the second node - the load balancer will still send it traffic because IIS is up. I can figure something out, eg. make a probe `dogs.aspx` which will run its own logic. I just thought being able to ensure that `http://dogs.com` wasn't returning a 500 error was a pretty standard thing to want to do! There's no easy way to do this unless you're using the app gateway which does allow for a hostname. I don't see any reason for this limitation - just frustrating :(